# How do I remove selected text from an input control?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Basically, I want to be able to detect:

1. if there is highlighted text inside of a text input
2. How to remove the selected text

I set up a fiddle to show how far I got, but I can't figure out how to remove the given text.

http://jsfiddle.net/z36Px/

Here is my markup

```
<input type='text' value='Hello World!' id='txtbox' />
<br />
<button id="btnSelect">select text</button>
<button id="btnRemove">remove selected text</button>
```

and my javascript

```
$("#btnSelect").click(function () {
    document.getElementById('txtbox').setSelectionRange(6, 12);
});
$("#btnRemove").click(function () {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        if (window.getSelection().deleteFromDocument) {
            window.getSelection().deleteFromDocument();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: if you know your range can you the use  `splice()` ?

Comment: This fiddle is a functional example.  In real world usage, I will not know my range.

Comment: There are lots of posts here on stackoverflow that address this sort of issue. Google `js delete text from textarea` or `jquery textarea get selected text`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on browser compatibility (ie9+ and others) you could use selectionEnd, selectionStart:

```
$("#btnRemove").click(function () {
    var ele  = document.getElementById('txtbox');
    var text = ele.value;

    text = text.slice(0, ele.selectionStart) + text.slice(ele.selectionEnd);
    ele.value = text;
});
```

[Working Fiddle in Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/z36Px/2/)

Comment: You could also save the original cursor position as `var cursorPos = ele.selectionStart` and then in the end restore it as: `ele.selectionStart = ele.selectionEnd = cursorPos`

Comment: In case you end up here and just wanted to simply delete the marked text, use: const sel = window.getSelection(); sel.deleteFromDocument();

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant, thank you!!